# Dynamic javascript within a custom control within an UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

Very simply, I have a custom ASP.NET control that in addition to rendering a textbox also outputs a javascript function and a call to that function.  The key to the problem here is that variables in the javascript may be different on each postback.

So I have the control inside of an UpdatePanel and below is an example of what the output javascript looks like.  Some of the variables passed to someStaticFunction are dynamic based on properties of the custom control (e.g. Visible).

```
$(function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(myFunction);
    myFunction();
});
function myFunction(sender, args) {
    someStaticFunction('false');    \\ "false" is written dynamically by the control's server side code
}
```

When the UpdatePanel posts back, depending on what the user chose, the page may now set the control's property to true.  While the javascript does get written out correctly (same as above except 'false' is 'true', false is still passed to someStaticFunction.

So the control is rendering the correct javascript after the postback however the page is running the javascript from the original post.

I hope that's clear and someone can offer a suggestion.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried evaluating the properties of the control in the pageLoad() function that gets called on every postback and calling someStaticFunction with that value instead of what gets generated server side?

A simple code example:

```
function pageLoad(){
    var value = $('#controlID').val();
    someStaticFunction(value);
}
```